# Does Sonar for Bamboo Add-on support branches after SonarQube 6.7?

Tags: sonarqube, bamboo

The `sonar.branch` parameter is deprecated starting from [SonarQube 6.7](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters).

Will branch analysis on Sonar for Bamboo still function after upgrading to Sonarqube 6.7 without having the [branch plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Branch+Plugin)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the plug-in still supports the old branching model even with version 6.7.